# Integral of a measurable function

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I do not know what should i keep as title for this question...

Question goes like this..

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ be a measurable function. If $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx=1$ prove that

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+f(x)}dx=\infty.$$

Hint that was given is : First show that $\{x:f(x)<1\}$ is of infinte measure.

I do not know how to proceed.. All that i could think about this is the following.

By $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx=1$  i see that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_{-n}^n f(x)dx=1$ i.e., given $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that  for all $n\geq N$ we have

$$\left|\int_{-n}^nf(x)dx-1\right|<\epsilon$$

I do not see any thing more than this..

Comment: You could show that set has infinite measure by showing its complement has finite measure...

Comment: Well, if $0\le f(x)<1$, then $\dfrac{1}{1+f(x)}>\dfrac12$. So I suggest you actually follow the hint.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich : By the time i prove that its complement has finite measure there is an answer doing the same thing that i have done.. Thanks... I got it

Comment: @G.Sassatelli : Your comment make so much of sense.. Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the hint, suppose that $\{x:f(x)<1\}$ had finite measure.  Then $\{x:f(x)\geq 1\}$ has infinite measure.  Then, $\{x:f(x)\geq 1\}$  has a subset $A$ of measure $2$.  But then,
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)dx\geq\int_Af(x)dx\geq\int_Adx=\mu(A)=2>1.
$$

Since $\{x:f(x)<1\}$ has infinite measure, use the hint of @G.Sassatelli (a very similar argument to the argument above) to finish the proof.

Comment: Thanks.... I like the idea that a subset of infinite measure has a subset of measure $2$.. It seems to be true that a subset of infinite measure should have  a subset of measure $l>0$ but i fail to give a proof for that... Let me try one more time..

Comment: Hint: If you consider the simple function $\chi_{f(x)\geq 1}(x)$, you can see that $\int_{-a}^a\chi_{\{f(x)\geq 1\}}(x)dx$ which gives the measure $\mu(\{f(x)\geq 1\}\cap(-a,a))$, which is a continuous function of $a$.  This function starts at $0$ when $a=0$ and approaches $\infty$ as $a$ grows.  So, by the intermediate value theorem, there is some value of $a$ where the measure is $2$.

Comment: ok... Can we say more generally that a set of infinite measure has a subset of any measure we wish for?

Answer (score 1):

For the hint, notice 
$$
1=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f=\int_{f<1}f+\int_{f\geq1}f
$$
Since $f\geq 0$, this implies $\int_{f< 1}f\geq 0$, while $\int_{f\geq1}f\geq\int_{f\geq1}1=m(\{x:f(x)\geq1\})$. Hence

$$
1=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f=\int_{f<1}f+\int_{f\geq1}f>m(\{x:f(x)\geq1\})
$$

Using this and the hint given in the comment, you can conclude the proof.