# $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow[0,\infty) $ is a measurable function, if $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)=1$, then $\int_{-\infty}^0\frac{1}{1+f(x)}=\infty$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I have to prove this result but I don't know where to start. The hint is, the measure of the set {$x:f(x)<1$} is $\infty$. Can someone help me?

Comment: Is there any issue applying the hint?

Comment: The problem is I don't know how to use the hint, I am new to this subject

Comment: Write $E=\{x\in(-\infty,0]:f(x)<1\}$. Since $f$ is non-negative and $\int_{-\infty}^{0}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x<\infty$, we can expect that the set on which $f$ takes large values is 'small'. This leads to the guess that $E$ has infinite Lebesgue-measure. Then check that, for $x \in E$ we have $1/(1+f(x)) \geq 1/2$, and so, the Lebesgue-measure of $E$ is bounded from above by $2\int_{-\infty}^{0}\mathrm{d}x/(1+f(x))$. If you can formalize these two observations, then you can prove the desired claim.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1676938/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1653381/42969

Comment: It seems that the proofs in the link are much shorter and straightforward. You may definitely want to give it a read.